# convert data structure into csv

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a data structure like the one shown below and I need to convert it into a csv file. I want the columns to be ordered in certain way.

**Input data structure**

```
{
       "total": {
              "a": 300, 
              "c": 300, 
              "b": 300, 
              "e": 300, 
              "d": 300
       }, 
       "japan": {
              "a": 12, 
              "c": 130, 
              "b": 223, 
              "e": 10, 
              "d": 51
       }, 
       "america": {
              "a": 1, 
              "c": 10, 
              "b": 2, 
              "e": 20, 
              "d": 5
       }, 
       "china": {
              "a": 1, 
              "c": 5, 
              "b": 23, 
              "e": 11, 
              "d": 9
       }
}
```

**Desired output**

```
category,total,japan,china,america
a,300,12,1,1
b,300,223,23,2
c,300,130,5,10
d,300,51,9,5
e,300,10,11,20
cat_total,1500,426,49,87
percentage,,28.4,0.032,0.058
```

**formula for percentage ( japan for example )**

```
percentage = 426/1500 * 100
where 426 is cat_total of Japan and 1500 is cat_total of total column
```

Code that I was able to come up with is as shown below

```
import csv
import sys

my_dict = { 'america' : { 'a' : 1,
                             'b' : 2,
                             'c' : 10,
                             'd' : 5,
                             'e' : 20
                            },
            'japan' : { 'a' : 12,
                             'b' : 223,
                             'c' : 130,
                             'd' : 51,
                             'e' : 10
                            },
            'total': {'a': 300,
                      'b': 300,
                      'c': 300,
                      'd': 300,
                      'e': 300,
                      },
            'china': {'a': 1,
                      'b': 23,
                      'c': 5,
                      'd': 9,
                      'e': 11
                      },

            }


category = set([c for country in my_dict for c in my_dict[country].keys()])


data_to_write = list()

for cat in category:
    temp = list()
    temp.append(cat)
    for country_name in my_dict:
        temp.append(my_dict[country_name][cat])
    data_to_write.append(temp)

csvfile = csv.writer(sys.stderr)
for row in data_to_write:
    csvfile.writerow(row)
```

**My requirement**

1. Need to calculate cat_total and percentage row.
2. I want the category, total and Japan as the first three columns of csv and  am ok with any order for remaining columns
3. in case of rows, I want cat_total as second last and percentage as last column.

It would be great if someone can help me on this. Thanks

Comment: Was my answer of any help?

Comment: @displayname Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I won't be able to use pandas in my environment for now.  I will try to explore pandas library, it sounds interesting to a beginner like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a pure python solution that could then be passed to the csv writer as you have already done.

```
# Get complete set of all keys used in sub-dictionaries (e.g. 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and 'e').
subkeys = set()
for k in d:
    subkeys.update(d[k].keys())
subkeys = sorted(subkeys)

# Get columns in desired order.
cols = ['category', 'total', 'japan']
cols += [k for k in d if k not in cols]

# Arrange data as a matrix.
data = [[k] + [d[col].get(k, 0) for col in cols[1:]] for k in subkeys]

# Add totals for each column.
data.append(['cat_total'] + [sum(row[col] for row in data) 
                             for col in range(1, len(d.keys()) + 1) ])

# Calculate percentage of total.
factor = 100. / data[-1][1]
data.append(['percentage', ''] + [round(n * factor, 3) for n in data[-1][2:]])

data_to_write = data
>>> data_to_write
[['a', 300, 12, 1, 1],
 ['b', 300, 223, 23, 2],
 ['c', 300, 130, 5, 10],
 ['d', 300, 51, 9, 5],
 ['e', 300, 10, 11, 20],
 ['cat_total', 1500, 426, 49, 38],
 ['percentage', '', 28.4, 3.267, 2.533]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (your new best friend when working with data/tables).

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
       "total": {
              "a": 300, 
              "c": 300, 
              "b": 300, 
              "e": 300, 
              "d": 300
       },
       # ... etc.
}

# Create DataFrame from dictionary (and transpose it)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).T

# Add new columns
df['cat_total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['percentage'] = df.sum(axis=1) *100 / df.T.total.sum()

# Transpose it again so we get the index right
df = df.T

# Save your DataFrame as csv 
df.to_csv('data.csv', index_label='category')
print(df) # Or print it ..
```

For installation just run

```
pip install pandas
```

Comment: How about the column orders and total and percentage row that I have mentioned in my post?

Comment: @chidori How do you calculate that `426` for Japan then I'll show you

Comment: thats sum of the respective column data

Comment: @chidori Well okay I am not 100% sure if this is really what you want but the code above would create your CSV table.

Comment: @chidori Also you might want to check out jupyter. Go to https://try.jupyter.org/ and click on `New > Python 3` and use the code above to play around. You'll love it and then you'll install it on your machine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
import csv

with open("data.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

with open("data.csv", "w") as file:
    csv_file = csv.writer(file)
    for item in data:
      //write your json data here
```

Comment: I am sorry, I doubt if this would give me desired results.